# What is the probability of getting a red ball?

Tags: probability

An  box has  6 red  and  4 blue  balls,  another  box has  3  red  and  6  blue  balls.  A  coin  toss decides which box is chosen: if it comes up heads, a ball is taken from the  first box, otherwise a ball is
taken from the second box.
What is the probability of getting a red ball?

Comment: I suggest that you write what you've tried, so it will be easier to guide you through the problem

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework and which show no effort.  What have you tried?   You must have some idea of how to attack the problem.  Where are you getting stuck?  People will meet you half way if you show that you aren't just asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: ok my bad. I will be more specific in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition on the box that was chosen: $P(\text{box } 1) = \frac{1}{2}= P(\text{box } 2)$ assuming the coin is fair.

Also $P(R|  \text{ box } 1) = \frac{6}{10}$. And $P(R | \text{ box } 2) = \frac{3}{9}$

Now $$P(R) =P(R|  \text{ box } 1)P(\text{box} 1) + P(R|  \text{ box } 2)P(\text{box } 2)$$

by the "law of total probabilities" (or some such name).